# How to unlock an iPad 2 Without Restoring Back to Original Factory Settings

Tags: ipad

My iPad is locked. Is there a way in which I can unlock it without having to restore it to factory settings? Is there a software program that helps?

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you cannot unlock your iPad, and your iPad is not "locked" in some other way. In this case, as far as I am aware, the best way is to back it up to a computer, then factory resetting it. After it has been reset, simply restore data back into the iPad, and the iPad will be like before but without the passcode lock.